# How to get info from main to void?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I have been tasked with using GLUT to ask the user to enter coordinates and display a rectangle. However, I can't seem to get the coordinates from "int main" to "void display".

Here is my code so far:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<gl/glut.h>

using namespace std;
void display(float yaxis, float xaxis)
{
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);

    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin (GL_QUADS);

    glColor3f(0, 0, 0);

    glVertex2f(yaxis, -xaxis);
    glVertex2f(yaxis, xaxis);
    glVertex2f(-yaxis, xaxis);
    glVertex2f(-yaxis, -xaxis);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();

}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    float xaxis;
    float yaxis;

    cout << "Please enter the co-ordinates for the x axis and press enter.";
    cin >> xaxis;
    cout << "You entered: " << xaxis
            << ".\n Please enter the co-ordinates for the y axis and press enter.";
    cin >> yaxis;
    cout << "You entered: " << yaxis << ".\n Here is your rectangle.";

    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitWindowSize(640, 500);

    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 10);

    glutCreateWindow("Triangle");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You get input from the user and immediately `return`. Did you not want that there?

Comment: `return` means leave the function now. Any code after `return` is ignored. Should be a compiler warning or two about that.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It's not a typo, but a poorly placed `return` isn't of much use to assist future questioners.

Comment: I have changed it so can anyone help me now?

Comment: @helphelp That's the declaration for the `glutDisplayFunc`: `void glutDisplayFunc(void (*func)(void));` while you're trying to pass `void display(float yaxis, float xaxis)` function (instead of a function **without** any parameters).

Comment: So can you explain what to change?

Comment: @helphelp You have to declare `float yaxis`and `float xaxis` as global static variables I believe. So both of them will available for `main` and `display` functions. While making your `display` function as taking no parameters: `void display() {...}`

Comment: Can you show an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`glutDisplayFunc` function has the following declaration:

```
void glutDisplayFunc(void (*func)(void));
```

Therefore you can't use your `display` function as you implemented it.
Here is an **quick** example that can fix your error:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<gl/glut.h>

using namespace std;
static float yaxis;
static float xaxis;
void display()
{
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);

    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBegin (GL_QUADS);

    glColor3f(0, 0, 0);

    glVertex2f(yaxis, -xaxis);
    glVertex2f(yaxis, xaxis);
    glVertex2f(-yaxis, xaxis);
    glVertex2f(-yaxis, -xaxis);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();

}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cout << "Please enter the co-ordinates for the x axis and press enter.";
    cin >> xaxis;
    cout << "You entered: " << xaxis
            << ".\n Please enter the co-ordinates for the y axis and press enter.";
    cin >> yaxis;
    cout << "You entered: " << yaxis << ".\n Here is your rectangle.";

    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitWindowSize(640, 500);

    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 10);

    glutCreateWindow("Rectangle");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You have been a great help!